# なぜか必要のないendを要求される

Tags: ruby

**質問に至った背景**

Rubyで入力された数の範囲の素数をもれなく求める関数を書いているのですが,なぜか不要な`end`キーワードを求められます.この`end`がどこの区切りかわからなかったので質問させていただきました.なお私個人としてはirb(下記ログ参照)でいう33行目の`end`は`コード中のendを要求する命令はすべてendで閉じられているため不要`だと考えています.

**問題のコード**
このコードは入力された数の範囲の素数を`エラトステネスのふるい`ではじき出す関数のみを定義してます.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def sieve(num);

      n = num;
      array_seed = [];

      while n > 1 do
   　　　　　array_seed << n;
　　　   　　n -= 1;
      end

      array_seed.reverse!;
      primes = [];

      while true do
　　　   　　array_seed_tmp = array_seed.shift;
　　　　　   primes << array_seed;

           break if !array_seed_tmp

           trashnum = [];

           array_seed.each do |x|
               trashnum << x; if x % array_seed_tmp == 0
           end
         primes -= trashnum
　    end
      array_string = primes.to_s;
      array_string.each do |y|
         print("#{y}\s");
      end
    end
end
```

これの場合`irb`のチェックが通ります.

```
psieve.rb(main):001:0> #!/usr/bin/env ruby
=> nil
psieve.rb(main):002:0> 
psieve.rb(main):003:0> def sieve(num);
psieve.rb(main):004:1>   
psieve.rb(main):005:1>       n = num;
psieve.rb(main):006:1>       array_seed = [];
psieve.rb(main):007:1> 
psieve.rb(main):008:1>       while n > 1 do
psieve.rb(main):009:2*    　　　　　array_seed << n;
psieve.rb(main):010:2> 　　　   　　n -= 1;
psieve.rb(main):011:2>       end
psieve.rb(main):012:1> 
psieve.rb(main):013:1>       array_seed.reverse!;
psieve.rb(main):014:1>       primes = [];
psieve.rb(main):015:1> 
psieve.rb(main):016:1>       while true do
psieve.rb(main):017:2* 　　　   　　array_seed_tmp = array_seed.shift;
psieve.rb(main):018:2> 　　　　　   primes << array_seed;
psieve.rb(main):019:2>          
psieve.rb(main):020:2>            break if !array_seed_tmp
psieve.rb(main):021:2>         
psieve.rb(main):022:2>            trashnum = [];
psieve.rb(main):023:2> 
psieve.rb(main):024:2>            array_seed.each do |x|
psieve.rb(main):025:3*                trashnum << x; if x % array_seed_tmp == 0
psieve.rb(main):026:4>            end
psieve.rb(main):027:3>          primes -= trashnum
psieve.rb(main):028:3> 　    end
psieve.rb(main):029:2>       array_string = primes.to_s;
psieve.rb(main):030:2>       array_string.each do |y|
psieve.rb(main):031:3*          print("#{y}\s");
psieve.rb(main):032:3>       end
psieve.rb(main):033:2>     end
psieve.rb(main):034:1> end
=> :sieve
psieve.rb(main):035:0> 
psieve.rb(main):036:0>
```

しかし33行目(下から4番目)の`end`を無効にすると構文エラーが起こり出処不明の`end`を要求されます.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def sieve(num);

      n = num;
      array_seed = [];

      while n > 1 do
   　　　　　array_seed << n;
　　　   　　n -= 1;
      end

      array_seed.reverse!;
      primes = [];

      while true do
　　　   　　array_seed_tmp = array_seed.shift;
　　　　　   primes << array_seed;

           break if !array_seed_tmp

           trashnum = [];

           array_seed.each do |x|
               trashnum << x; if x % array_seed_tmp == 0
           end
         primes -= trashnum
　    end
      array_string = primes.to_s;
      array_string.each do |y|
         print("#{y}\s");
      end
    #end
end
```

```
psieve.rb(main):001:0> #!/usr/bin/env ruby
=> nil
psieve.rb(main):002:0> 
psieve.rb(main):003:0> def sieve(num);
psieve.rb(main):004:1>   
psieve.rb(main):005:1>       n = num;
psieve.rb(main):006:1>       array_seed = [];
psieve.rb(main):007:1> 
psieve.rb(main):008:1>       while n > 1 do
psieve.rb(main):009:2*    　　　　　array_seed << n;
psieve.rb(main):010:2> 　　　   　　n -= 1;
psieve.rb(main):011:2>       end
psieve.rb(main):012:1> 
psieve.rb(main):013:1>       array_seed.reverse!;
psieve.rb(main):014:1>       primes = [];
psieve.rb(main):015:1> 
psieve.rb(main):016:1>       while true do
psieve.rb(main):017:2* 　　　   　　array_seed_tmp = array_seed.shift;
psieve.rb(main):018:2> 　　　　　   primes << array_seed;
psieve.rb(main):019:2>          
psieve.rb(main):020:2>            break if !array_seed_tmp
psieve.rb(main):021:2>         
psieve.rb(main):022:2>            trashnum = [];
psieve.rb(main):023:2> 
psieve.rb(main):024:2>            array_seed.each do |x|
psieve.rb(main):025:3*                trashnum << x; if x % array_seed_tmp == 0
psieve.rb(main):026:4>            end
psieve.rb(main):027:3>          primes -= trashnum
psieve.rb(main):028:3> 　    end
psieve.rb(main):029:2>       array_string = primes.to_s;
psieve.rb(main):030:2>       array_string.each do |y|
psieve.rb(main):031:3*          print("#{y}\s");
psieve.rb(main):032:3>       end
psieve.rb(main):033:2>     #end
psieve.rb(main):034:2> end
psieve.rb(main):035:1> 
psieve.rb(main):036:1> 
SyntaxError (psieve.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
```

**推測**
何度も再起動したりRubyを入れ直したりしてみましたがエラーは解決されなかったのでおそらく処理系のエラーバグとは考えにくいので,自分がどこかで書き損じているのだと思います(元々はFedoraでこのような構文解析エラーに遭遇しましたが,緊急用のArchLabsでも同様のエラーが出たので)

伺いたいことを纏めると,

- 33行目のendはどこのendなのか?

ということです.

最後になりましたが,OSはFedora30とArchLabs(最新版)でRubyのバージョンが共に2.6.3です.

Comment: `trashnum << x; if x % array_seed_tmp == 0` で `;` が入ってしまっているためですね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

質問に記載のサンプルには全角空白がありますがわざとですよね？

とりあえず、25行目のIFに対応するendが無いものと思われます。
`ruby-beautify`をかけたものが下記になります。

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def sieve(num)

        n = num;
        array_seed = [];

        while n > 1 do
                array_seed << n;
                n -= 1;
        end

        array_seed.reverse!;
        primes = [];

        while true do
                array_seed_tmp = array_seed.shift;
                primes << array_seed;

                break if !array_seed_tmp

                trashnum = [];

                array_seed.each do |x| trashnum << x;
                        if x % array_seed_tmp == 0
                        end
                        primes -= trashnum
                end
                array_string = primes.to_s;
                array_string.each do |y|
                        print("#{y}\s");
                end
        end
end
```

Comment: このコードは自宅で論理設計のノートをMarkdownでとりながら書いたものなのでもしかすると全角スペースが混じっていたかもしれません.ご教示の通りコード中の25行目に不必要な`;`があったので取り除いて実行してみたところデバッグのチェックが通りました.本当にありがとうございます.

Comment: ちなみに、Rubyでは「;」は使わないほうが良いと思います。普通はなくても問題ありませんし、何らかの理由で複数行を一行にまとめたいとき、区切りとして使うことはありますが、これも滅多に見かけませんので。